# Visual Studio Code: Moving the terminal back to the bottom

Tags: visual-studio-code

I accidentally clicked the button that moves the terminal from the bottom to the right. How do I get it back to the bottom?

Clicking the split button again just splits the terminal.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Just move the `Terminal` split bar to the left to widen the `Terminal` window so that the icon of `Move to Bottom` can appear so you can click it.

**UPDATE**

The `Move to Right` and `Move to Bottom` icons was removed as of [Update 1.29.1 on October 2018](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_29#_panel-position-button-to-context-menu).

You can now `right-click` the title area of the `Terminal` window so that you can find `Move Panel to Right` or `Move Panel to Bottom`, alternatively, you may click `View > Appearance > Toggle Panel Position`.

Comment: @rht341 I couldn't find it either; not very intuitive. If you somehow placed the `Terminal` too much to the right, you won't see the icon until you move it to the left.

Comment: You don't know how much you take for granted until it is gone :( I think in v3 it is completely removed since they using visual studio code embedded

Comment: This is the perfect answer. the icon mentioned in this answer is the tiny terminal icon that comes left corner. just click on it and drag it to where you need it.

Comment: 71+ upvotes means there's definitely something not intuitive with the GUI :-/

Comment: Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/7237354/gopi-p. You need to drag small icon to the bottom next to 'output' 'debug console'..

Answer (score 30):

Right click on terminal icon and select *Reset location*:

[image]

Comment: The image link is broken.

Comment: Re added image @PeterMortensen

Answer (score 12):

In the latest version, I was able to click on the terminal icon and drag and drop it to the bottom of the window.

Visual Studio Code version information:

- Version: 1.66.1
- Commit: 8dfae7a5cd50421d10cd99cb873990460525a898
- Date: 2022-04-06T14:49:52.288Z (5 days ago)
- Electron: 17.2.0
- Chromium: 98.0.4758.109
- Node.js: 16.13.0
- V8: 9.8.177.11-electron.0
- OS: Darwin arm64 21.4.0

Answer (score 6):

Just run:

`CMD SHIFT P -> Toggle Panel Position`

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, and it was solved on a MacBook Pro 2018.

Moving the cursor to the terminal.

[image]

Comment: That ought to be [represented in text as well](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/).

Answer (score 2):

After the update 1.66 for Visual Studio Code:

Step 1: Click view in title, Editor Layout, Split down 
Step 2: right click on the Terminal name in the Secondary Side bar 
Step 3: click on Move terminal to editor area

Answer (score 1):

Click on the indicated icon in the terminal. That's all.

[image: Terminal position]

Comment: As @Ali Heikal mentioned , this was removed

Answer (score 1):

"Move Secondary Side Bar Views To Panel" (the one that worked for me) and "Move Terminal into Panel" options are available in the latest version of vscode on Mac as of Dec 2022
Cmd+Shift_P and "Move Secondary Side Bar Views To Panel" or "Move Terminal into Panel"

[image: Cmd+Shift+P Move Secondary Side Bar Views To Panel]

[image: Cmd+Shift+P Move Terminal into Panel]

Answer (score 0):

Update Nov 2022:

Terminal > New Terminal and attaching it as a tab to the bottom of the editor. You can then use the terminal.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio Code?

Answer (score 0):

For Visual Studio Code version 1.84.2, moving the terminal window from the right to the bottom:

Ensure that the bottom window is wide enough to show at least one window title (e.g., "DEBUG CONSOLE"). [Drag the terminal icon [>_] from terminal window on the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMHAA.jpg) to next to a window title in the bottom window.

[A vertical bar shows up at that location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHfqz.jpg), indicating that the terminal window will be moved there if dropped. Drop the terminal icon there to move the terminal window to bottom, though it may not become the current bottom window (tab). Change the window tab at the bottom to [make terminal the current window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/he6q1.jpg).

Moving the terminal window from the bottom to the right:

[Move the mouse over the "TERMINAL" label of the terminal window and drag it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fytrq.jpg) to the right edge of the window. A space will open up in the right side of the Visual Studio Code window with [a message "Drag a view here to display"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9ERv.jpg).

Drop the dragged "TERMINAL" label in the space opened up in the right side of the Visual Studio Code window. The terminal window now shows in the right side of the Visual Studio Code window. [This picture was put up later on and so does not exactly match earlier pictures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4tU7.jpg).

Visual Studio Code version information:

- Version: 1.84.2 (user setup)
- Commit: 1a5daa3a0231a0fbba4f14db7ec463cf99d7768e
- Date: 2023-11-09T10:51:52.184Z
- Electron: 25.9.2
- ElectronBuildId: 24603566
- Chromium: 114.0.5735.289
- Node.js: 18.15.0
- V8: 11.4.183.29-electron.0
- OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19044

Answer (score 0):

I came across this question when accidentally I hit a key combination that collapsed my terminal. If that happened to you, look to the top right and click on the second icon that shows a highlighted bottom.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

While in the terminal, follow the below:

[Enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oz59H.png)