# Integrate terminal back to bottom panel in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I moved my terminal window out of the bottom panel on VSCode where it used to sit next to problems, output, debug console, etc. to the side panel on the right.

[image]

I want it to go back to where it used to be as default at the bottom as I've artistically drawn in the photo. Please could someone help me do this? I have tried Google and playing with the appearance settings.

Comment: Duplicate of [Move terminal back to bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52368079/move-terminal-back-to-bottom)

Comment: This is not a duplicate. The user in that question hadn't removed Terminal from the bottom panel. They had just created a terminal section to the right of the bottom panel.

Comment: Just drag the icon to the far left - the arrow in a box with an underline - to the bottom panel.

Comment: That temporarily moves it down on top of the problems panel though. I want it to sit as a tab in the problems panel again. I don’t want to have to drag it to the bottom and have two panels at the bottom every time I login.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue recently.  I had pulled out the terminal to the side and couldn't figure out how to put it back in the bottom panel.
(1) Ensure that drag and drop is enabled in settings, and
(2) I had to drag from the icon on the top left of the terminal window where the PowerShell icon was. No right-click or drag-and-drop from the top bar, just where the terminal type icon was.